# num_rows Always shows Zero value in PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am totally new to this PHP.

I am just practicing Prepared statements.
I know there few questions which is related to mine.

But nothing Helped me.

This is my php code Which returns always `num_rows` equal to Zero.

But there is a data in my table

```
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                        $my_id = 49;
                        $content = $_POST['cont'];
                        $content_date = date('d-m-y');
                        $check = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE user_id = ?";
                        $stmt = $con->prepare($check);
                        $stmt->bind_param("i",$my_id);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->fetch();
                        $numberofrows = $stmt->num_rows;
                        $stmt->close();
                        echo '<h1>'.$numberofrows.'</h1>';


                     }
```

Comment: Are you sure 49 is a good id?

Comment: yes there is value for it

Comment: Well if there is only 1 row and you `fetch()` it, then there are 0 rows when you check `num_rows()`.

Comment: Yes It always shows Zero @AbraCadaver

Comment: Try to return `SELECT count(user_id) as usercounter FROM post WHERE user_id = ?` and change num_rows to normal fetching.

Comment: @vigneshwarar What he means is that after you fetch it, there are no more rows - meaning that the number of rows left is 0. Try moving the `$stmt->num_rows;` above `$stmt->fetch();`

Comment: And you're not storing the `fetch()` anywhere so just remove it.

Comment: It worked me with a procedural way mysqli_query But not in prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

Use () look like this... $numberofrows = $stmt->num_rows(); and try.

Answer (score 0):

Guys Thanx For your Ans 
Finally My friend helped me to solve this.
We have to store the result before we calling num_rows

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

It works fine now